# How to connect to mysql with eclipse in android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to connect to  mysql database in android eclipse and am using also 
mysql-connector-java-3.1.12-bin . 
But it shows me the message: failure due to underlying exception.
And it doesn't connect yet I am using  the same thing to connect in netbeans to my Java programs .
Any help will be appreciated.

package com.bookapp;

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class PersonalInfo extends Activity {


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.personalinfo);



            try
            {
                StudentDA stud= new StudentDA();
                for (String jshdjsd: stud.GetAllUniversities()) {
                    Toast tt=Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, jshdjsd,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    tt.show();
                }
            //for eastud.GetAllUniversities()));
            }
            catch(SQLException ss)
            {
                Toast tt=Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, "You have an Error "+ss.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                tt.show();
            }



            //create reference to layout widget/control
            Button btnNext=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

            //create reference to textbox
            final   EditText txtStudNo,txtName,txtSurname;  // text box
            final Spinner cmbGender=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cmbGender); // combo box

           txtStudNo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStudentNo);

           txtName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);

           txtSurname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);


           //set the button onclick event listener
           btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if (txtStudNo.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast tt=Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, "Please Enter Student No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    tt.show();
                }
                else if (txtName.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast tt=Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, "Please Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    tt.show();
                }
                else if (txtSurname.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast tt=Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, "Please Enter Surname", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    tt.show();
                }
                else if (cmbGender.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
                {
                    Toast tt=Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, "Please Select Gender", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    tt.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Student.Gender=cmbGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Student.studentNo=txtStudNo.getText().toString();
                    Student.Name=txtName.getText().toString();
                    Student.Surname=txtSurname.getText().toString();

                    // Go to the next form 

                    Intent i = new Intent (PersonalInfo.this,ContactInfo.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //////End of me next 


                    //Toast tt=Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, "Thanks "+     Student.Name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //  tt.show();
                }



            }
        });

        }


    }
```

Comment: And what does say Google about this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect mysql database with android. You can use webservices to call database. Some examples for webservices are SOAP and RESTFUL. You can use either one of the to call db.

Refer the following example to call webservice:
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/

You can use SQL Lite to make mini db in andorid. Google on SQL Lite to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

Create a java project in Eclipse

create package Name `com.example.sql`

Include `mysqlconnector.jar` in your project

Below code for Local system

```
package com.example.employeeinduction;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public EditText uname,pwd;
    Button btnlog1;
    TextView invalid;
    public Button btncancel1;
    public String db_select;
     String mUname;
     String mPwd;
    String temp;
    Intent intObj;
    Intent intent = null;
    SessionManager session;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    private String SERVICE_URL = "http://10.54.3.208:8080/";
    private final String SERVICE_URL = Urlmanager.Address;
    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final String Is_Login = "Is_Login";
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPREFERENCES";
    private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        invalid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        btnlog1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
          session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext()); 
        btnlog1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                mUname=uname.getText().toString();
                mPwd=pwd.getText().toString();
                String d="true";
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("Is_Login",d);
                editor.putString("EMP_ID",mUname);
                editor.putString("EMP_PWD",mPwd);
                editor.commit();
                if(!mUname.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !mPwd.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, isInternetPresent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(isInternetPresent)
                    {


                    try
                    {
                        validat_user(mUname,mPwd);
                        session.createLoginSession(mUname,mPwd);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        display("Network error.\nPlease check with your network settings.");
                        uname.setText("");
                        pwd.setText("");
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        display("No Internet Connection...");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    invalid.setText("Please enter the data");
                }
            }
        });
    }

        /*@Override
        protected void onResume() 
        {
              SharedPreferences sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 
              Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              if (sharedpreferences.contains(mUname))
              {
              if(sharedpreferences.contains(mPwd)){
                 Intent i = new Intent(this,Design_Activity.class);
                 startActivity(i);
              }
              }
              super.onResume();


    }*/
    public void display(String msg) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    private void validat_user(String stg1, String stg2)
    {
        db_select=stg1;
        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "Login in progress...");

        wst.addNameValuePair("EMP_ID", stg1);
        wst.addNameValuePair("EMP_PWD", stg2);

        wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL });

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void no_net()
    {
        display( "No Network Connection");
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You don't have internet connection.\nElse please check the Internet Connection Settings.");
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_info);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {   
                alertDialog.cancel();
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("Use Local DataBase", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                display( "Accessing local DataBase.....");
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

        private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

        // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT =12000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT =12000;

        private int taskType = POST_TASK;
        private Context mContext = null;
        private String processMessage = "Processing...";

        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

        public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

            this.taskType = taskType;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.processMessage = processMessage;
        }

        public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void showProgressDialog() {

            pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
            pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
            pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDlg.setCancelable(false);
            pDlg.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            showProgressDialog();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url = urls[0].toString();
            String result = "";
            HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);
            if (response == null) {
                return result;
            } else {

                try {

                    result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }

            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            handleResponse(response);
            pDlg.dismiss();

        }

        // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
        private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

            HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            return htpp;
        }

        private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

            // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
            // DefaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                switch (taskType) {

                case POST_TASK:

                    HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost(url);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    break;
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            //  display("Remote DataBase can not be connected.\nPlease check network connection.");

                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                return null;

            }

            return response;
        }

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

            // Return full string
            return total.toString();
        }

    }
    public void handleResponse(String response) 

    {    
    //display("Response:"+response);
        if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            JSONObject jso;
            try {
                jso = new JSONObject(response);


                    String status = jso.getString("status");
                    int valid=jso.getInt("valid");
              //     display("Welcome : "+UName);
                 if(valid>0)
                 {
                    if( status.equalsIgnoreCase("") || status==null ||  status.equalsIgnoreCase("Failed"))
                    {
                        invalid.setText("Invalid password");
                        //reset();
                        pwd.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //session.createLoginSession(mUname,mPwd);
                        //display(status);
                        intObj=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Design_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intObj);
                        MainActivity.this.finish();     
                    }

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     invalid.setText("Invalid userid");
                     uname.setText("");
                 }
                }
            catch (JSONException e1) {

                Log.e(TAG, e1.getLocalizedMessage(), e1);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            display("Could not able to reach Server!");
        }


    }
    public void reset()
    {


        pwd.setText("");
        uname.setText("");
    }

}
```

[Refer this link for Rest web srvice](http://avilyne.com/?p=105)

Comment: Okay is this gonna connect to andriod app?